# Using EntitySetController

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm new to WebAPI + OData, but have jumped in the deep end and am currently working with the latest pre-release version. I understand that I choose to support whichever CRUD operations I want, but I'm unclear how I should be going about it. There seems to be a lack of resources on the web which is understandable given that it's all quite new.

My assumption at the moment is that I should be overriding the following methods for each CRUD operation:

```
Create (POST) : CreateEntity
Read (GET): Get
Update (PUT/PATCH): UpdateEntity/PatchEntity
Delete (DELETE): Delete
```

Is that right? Should I generally leave the Post() / Put() / Patch() methods and other methods alone? (These seem to just call the above methods)

If anyone can recommend a good learning resource for all of this it'd be appreciated too.

Comment: can you clarify what you meant by `latest pre-release version`? Are you not using Web API 2 (assembly version 5.0)?

Comment: It may just be the latest version. I've been introducing myself to a lot of new libraries lately so I've likely got mixed up. I am using Web API 2.

Comment: Ok if you are using VS 2013, we have a nice scaffolding experience for OData where you can create a controller for OData based on `ODataController`...in general going forward it is recommended to inherit from `ODataController`...

Comment: Check the following blog post regarding odata scaffolding: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/08/odata-scaffolding.aspx

Comment: I'm not on VS2013, unfortunately. I'm using VS2012. I notice that EntitySetController derives from ODataController. Is EntitySetController going to be phased out in favour of ODataController? The few articles I've read about OData in Web API 2 have actually recommended that EntitySetController be used over ODataController, so I'm a little confused.